# $\mathbb{E}(\alpha^Y)$, where $Y$ is negative binomial

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

It is given that $\alpha>0$ and that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\begin{pmatrix} y+k-1\\ y \end{pmatrix} (1-p)^kp^y \end{equation}

are there any ideas how to calculate expected value of $\alpha^Y$?

I have managed to obtain
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(\alpha^Y)=(1-p)^k\Bigg(1+k\alpha p\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix} z+k\\ z \end{pmatrix}(\alpha p)^z \Bigg)
\end{equation}
but the series converges if and only if $|\alpha p| <1$, thus I cannot proceed further with this expression. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. Your defn of a Negative Binomial does not accord with the usual definitions of Neg Binomial that I am familiar with. Are you sure that you have entered it correctly; if yes, please provide a source. 2. In any event, in what way is that which you seek different to finding the pgf?

Comment: $Y$ is the number of widgets succesfully produced before the $k$th failure.

Comment: Isn't this proportional to $M_Y(t)$ the moment generating function at $t= 1$?